# How to display all rows from one table if there are no rows with matching criteria to count in second table

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

I have two tables. "members" is list of all members, "stats" is a list of dates worked. The shared field is memberID. I need a COUNT of the number of days each person worked and I want everyone listed in the output table, even if they have not yet had a work day.

Simplified database structure is:

```
**members**                 **stats**       
memberID lname    fname     memberID    date    statsID
1        Mertz    Fred      1        2017-12-31    1
2        Doe      Jane      3        2017-12-31    2
3        Smith    Frank     4        2017-12-31    3
4        Ricardo  Lucy      2        2018-12-31    4
5        Starr    Ringo     4        2018-12-31    5
                            2        2019-05-05    6
                            3        2019-05-05    7
```

Output desired is:

```
memberID  lname  fname  Total Days 
2         Doe    Jane       2 
1         Mertz  Fred       1 
4         Ricardo Lucy      2 
3         Smith   Frank     2 
5         Starr   Ringo     0 OR blank
```

Ringo has not yet worked any days and does NOT appear on the output table.

My code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT  u.*,
   COUNT(s.memberID)as tot_days
   FROM members u
   LEFT JOIN stats s
    ON s.memberID = u.memberID 
    GROUP BY s.memberID
    ORDER BY lname,fname";

$members = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($members)){ 
        $row = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row);
        echo <<< HTML  etc.
```

This does everything I want it to do EXCEPT include those members who have not yet worked a day. JOIN, LEFT JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN all produce the same result. I tried LEFT and RIGHT INNER JOIN, if those even exist, which produced error `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given`.

Someone suggested using `COALESCE (COUNT(s.memberID),0) as tot_days`but that just produces the same error as above.

I've been at this for days and am getting just a teensy bit frustrated!

Comment: So give [mysqli_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) the parameter that it wants, `mysqli_error($dbc)`, and see what the error is. Might be something about the incorrect use of the aggregation (columns listed after `SELECT` that aren't an argument to an aggregation function nor listed in the `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Miken32's solution worked, sort of. It pulls up one of several new members without work dates.  My sample should have included more than one. I tried to add a comment to his post but it won't let me.

Comment: Group by u.memberid

Comment: Is that your original query or has it been edited? Because it does return according to your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.*
     , COUNT(DISTINCT s.date) tot_days
  FROM members u
  LEFT 
  JOIN stats s
    ON s.memberID = u.memberID
 GROUP 
    BY u.memberID
 ORDER 
    BY u.lname
     , u.fname
```

Comment: Rather than simply answering the question you should also explain why your answer is better/different from the code in the OP's question.

Comment: @BevHorn Change `WHERE` to `AND`

Comment: Thanks Strawberry and How dumb am I! Your new suggestion works just fine. Now, with luck I'll be able to combine them into one. But at least I now have something that works.

Answer (score -1):

u will have to reframe your query

```
create table members (id int primary key auto_increment, lname varchar(30), fname varchar(30));
insert into members values (1, 'Mertz',   'Fred') ,(2, 'Doe',     'Jane') ,(3, 'Smith',   'Frank'),(4, 'Ricardo', 'Lucy') ,(5, 'Starr',   'Ringo');


create table stats (member_id int, dates date, stat_id int);
insert into stats values (1, '2017-12-31', 1),(3, '2017-12-31', 2),(4, '2017-12-31', 3),(2, '2018-12-31', 4),(4, '2018-12-31', 5),(2, '2019-05-05', 6),(3, '2019-05-05', 7);



mysql> (select 
    -> m.id,
    -> m.fname,
    -> count(*) as total_days
    -> from 
    -> members m inner join stats s on m.id = s.member_id
    -> group by m.id)
    -> union
    -> (select
    -> m.id,
    -> m.fname,
    -> 0 as total_days
    -> from
    -> members m where not exists ( select * from stats s where m.id = s.member_id));
+----+-------+------------+
| id | fname | total_days |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | Fred  |          1 |
|  3 | Frank |          2 |
|  4 | Lucy  |          2 |
|  2 | Jane  |          2 |
|  5 | Ringo |          0 |
+----+-------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Strawberry , you are correct, it entirely depends on what we count. For this scenario i have made such comment.

Comment: @Strawberry edited as per your suggestion. your answer is really better. i hope my suggestion is eligible for upvoting!

Comment: I think this answer is predicated on an incorrect analysis, so I hope it doesn't get upvoted. Sorry :-(